# Running script inside Geany & IDLE do not work

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle, geany

**EDIT** Replying to Rohan's comment here...
So I've tried *import sys* and *sys.path* for both in IDLE and in the terminal and the paths are different, not sure if that's where the problem is.

The code I'm trying to run is...

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.time.wait(3000)
```

If I run the code in a terminal it works like it's supposed to, but I try it in IDLE it gets stuck on line with the Module Error.
**CLOSE EDIT**

I have searched through the already asked questions but couldn't find a solution to the issue I'm having.  I have IDLE installed with Python 3.6.3.(if I type python3 in a terminal though I get Python 3.6.5)  I've installed pip3 and the module pygame. However when I run my code I get the Module Not Found Error: No module named pygame.

If I run the code in the terminal directory everything works fine.  So I thought I'd try another text editor Geany.  After following all the instructions I can't even get Hello World to run on that.  A terminal opens but freezes.  The Compile and Execute lines were written exactly as they were supposed to be. I've tried updating and restarting my laptop but nothing works.

I'm just starting and following along with a couple books and everything has been going fine until this point but now I can't figure out what's going on.  The only thing I can think of is IDLE only recognizes python 3.6.3, but if I type python3 into a terminal it says Python 3.6.5.  I've tried updating and reinstalling IDLE but nothing seems to work.  I can't even remove it.  I haven't had any problems with code in IDLE until now and it's driving me crazy.  Is there any way I can just reinstall everything and start it over fresh?

I apologize if this isn't written properly, it's my first post and the little guide on the right was covered up with some similar questions that aren't similar as I was reading it...

Comment: Did you name the file pygame.py? If so, the computer recognizes the file, not the module, and it gives the error. If not, have you checked whether the installation files are 64/32 bit consistent?

Comment: Also, can you post you code? It's easier to understand the question that way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated my original post since I couldn't fit everything into this comment box, thanks.

Comment: Also as to whether the files are 64 or 32 I have no idea.  I can't figure out where they were even downloaded to.  I thought they would be in my module folder or somewhere in the python folder in general but can't find them  ....

Comment: First, do "pip3 freeze" in the terminal and check if pygame is installed. If it's installed, try uninstalling pygame with "pip3 uninstall pygame". I can only say its a problem with installation, so try downloading pygame with the installer at its official website: https://www.pygame.org/download.shtml. Just make sure you don't have any older versions of pygame before installing.

Comment: It is unusual to have both 3.6.3 and 3.6.5 separately installed.  If pygame is installed for 3.6.5 (but not 3.6.3) and `python3` in the terminal starts 3.6.5, then `python3 -m idlelib` should start IDLE with 3.6.5 and code run with IDLE so started should be able to import pygame.  If this works, please say so and I will post this as an answer instead of a guess.

Comment: Answer!  Thank you so much, Terry! I figured that was it and have been trying to uninstall/reinstall IDLE for days now.  I tried Geany but that gave me other issues.  Do you know if there's a way I can set IDLE up so that it runs 3.6.5 when I open it from my drop down window?  Or do I have to run that command from a terminal each time?  Thanks again, I can get back to learning now!

Answer (score 0):

*[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (…)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/6709630)*

Answer from @Terry Jan Reedy in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196288/running-script-inside-geany-idle-do-not-work#comment87463961_50196288):

> It is unusual to have both 3.6.3 and 3.6.5 separately installed. If
>   pygame is installed for 3.6.5 (but not 3.6.3) and python3 in the
>   terminal starts 3.6.5, then python3 -m idlelib should start IDLE with
>   3.6.5 and code run with IDLE so started should be able to import pygame.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the name of the file is pygame.py:
This file will be read/reached and NOT the pygame extension.